# Перетаскивание элемента за любую часть

Tags: c#, winforms

Создал кастомный контрол, у которого есть только текст. Нужно, что бы весь контрол можно было перемещать не зависимо от того, нажал юзер по тексту или по форме.

Пока единственным вариантом вижу навешивание события нажатия на каждый label. А существует другой вариант?

Comment: На одном контроле несколько лейблов или что? Каким боком тут нажатие по форме?

Comment: попробуйте использовать событие нажатия на контрол непосредственно, он же как целый объект

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Добавьте в своей проект следующий контрол-лейбл:

```
class PassThroughLabel : Label
{
    protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
    {
        const int WM_NCHITTEST = 0x0084;
        const int HTTRANSPARENT = (-1);

        if (m.Msg == WM_NCHITTEST)
        {
            m.Result = (IntPtr)HTTRANSPARENT;
        }
        else
        {
            base.WndProc(ref m);
        }
    }
}
```

Используйте именно их для размещения на кастомном контроле. Они прозрачные для событий мыши, клики на них будут передаваться родительскому контролу. В итоге перетаскивание будет работать и при нажатии на них.