# Обработка MouseDown всегда

Tags: c#, winforms

Пытаюсь реализовать перемещение формы, с borderStyle - None. 
Использую следующий код в MouseDown на форме.

```
        base.Capture = false;
        Message m = Message.Create(base.Handle, 0xa1, new IntPtr(2), IntPtr.Zero);
        this.WndProc(ref m);
```

При пустой форме он работает отлично, однако при добавлении элементов на форму(например table layout panel) это перестает работать. Как сделать, чтобы форма всегда обрабатывала нажатие вне зависимости на какой элемент мы нажали? Либо как возможно реализовать передачу нажатия mouse down элемента дальше форме.

Comment: А как вы думаете, для чего в окошках сделана верхняя граница (border)?

Comment: Если всё же, вам нужно использовать только область формы, на которую ещё что то размещается, то пробрасывайте компоненту в метод MouseDown вызов метода Form_MouseDown с вычислением смещения (форма располагается со смещением 0,0, а компонент лежит в точке Left,Top, как рассчитать смещение, думаю, вы поймёте)

Comment: Мне не подходит стандартный border поэтому и сделал borderStyle - none

Comment: В принципе я разобрался как сделать по другому, однако вышло куда более больше кода.

Comment: Вы не поняли вопроса. Прочитайте его ещё раз. Я ни слова не сказал о том что вам не надо так делать. Вопрос заключался принципиально в другом.

Comment: Суть вынесения бордера в том, что программа не знает на что именно вы хотите нажать. Вы же делаете сквозной клик. Когда я захочу выбрать запись в таблице, ваша программа ещё и кликнет на форму, а я хотел не этого... И что будет если я попытаюсь сделать Drag/Drop записи из таблицы в таблицу? А ничего не будет, в вашем подходе такое даже невозможно.

Comment: А как можно реализовать с помощью этого же кода перемещение формы, но уже при обработке mouse down на компоненте(например panel), который используется вместо border'a?

Comment: Так же как и на форме. У компонентов тоже есть MouseDown. Что мешает передать код от него другому событию?

Comment: Вот [так](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/824537/184217) можно сделать контрол прозрачным для кликов. Но при этом, как уже указали в комментариях, может нарушиться нормальная работа компонентов, которые должны реагировать на нажатия.

Comment: "У компонентов тоже есть MouseDown" попробовал сделать так и ничего не вышло.

Answer (score 0):

Т.к вместо заголовка я использую TableLayoutPanel в котором находятся еще и другие компоненты, например, Label, PictureBox и т.д.

Я решил воспользоваться таким способом :

Создаем user control, добавляем на него необходимые компоненты. В коде user control'a пишем следующий код :

```
public partial class CustomHeader : UserControl
{
    public event EventHandler<MouseEventArgs> HeaderMouseDown;

    public event EventHandler<MouseEventArgs> HeaderMouseMove;

    public CustomHeader()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        SubscribeOnMouseDown();
    }

    private void SubscribeOnMouseDown()
    {
        MouseDown += OnMouseDown;

        Subscribe(Controls);
    }

    private void Subscribe(ControlCollection controls)
    {
        foreach(Control control in controls)
        {
            if(control.HasChildren)
            {
                Subscribe(control.Controls);
            }
        }

        foreach(Control control in controls)
        {
            control.MouseDown += OnMouseDown;
            control.MouseMove += OnMouseMove;
        }
    }

    private void OnMouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        HeaderMouseMove?.Invoke(sender, e);
    }

    private void OnMouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        HeaderMouseDown?.Invoke(sender, e);
    }
}
```

Далее в коде формы пишем следующие :

```
    private Point Last { get; set;}

    public MainForm(ApplicationContext context)
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        _customHeader.HeaderMouseDown += Form_MouseDown;
        _customHeader.HeaderMouseMove += Form_MouseMove;
    }

    private void Form_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if(e.Button == MouseButtons.Left)
        {
            Last = MousePosition;
        }
    }

    private void Form_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if(e.Button == MouseButtons.Left)
        {
            Point cur = MousePosition;
            int dx = cur.X - Last.X;
            int dy = cur.Y - Last.Y;
            Point loc = new Point(Location.X + dx, Location.Y + dy);
            Location = loc;
            Last = cur;
        }
    }
```

Есть еще альтернативные способ, но он работают только если у вас header это один элемент(например panel).